# Codeigniter track mysql error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am running a codeigniter project.

I am trying to track a mysql error, but all I get is a reference to:

system\database\DB_driver.php

I have already set the environment to 'development' and $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE; in config/database.php , but to no avail.

Anybody got any solutions?

Comment: Check whether mysql is running or not. Use SQLYog to test connect to your server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your db settings...

project folder -> application -> config -> database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname']  = 'your_host_name';
$db['default']['username']  = 'db_username';
$db['default']['password']  = 'password';
$db['default']['database']  = 'db_name';
```

then you check the accuracy of your database, username and password in phpmyadmin..
sometimes phpmyadmin services can be stoped.. then you have to start it. :)

Comment: phpmyadmin is a database administration tool, not a database

Comment: yes.. I wanted to say there can be some errors/issues with his db name and the availability of the services that given by that database administration tool. Aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the CodeIgniter Hooks to log all SQL queries then be able to debug your program. You can find step by step tutorial [here](http://4rapiddev.com/php/codeigniter-save-or-log-all-mysql-queries/).